# How should this sentence be understood? 「小さなゴンドラに四人は手狭だ」

Tags: grammar

> 小【ちい】さなゴンドラに四人【よにん】は手狭【てぜま】だ

Could に be used as part of a modifying clause without verbs like ある, いる to describe 四人【よにん】 to mean "4 people in a small cabin is too cramped" or does it mean "4 people are too cramped for a small cabin"?

Am I correct to think 「小【ちい】さなゴンドラに四人【よにん】」is the equivalent to the English "4 people in a cabin" vs "4 people who are in a cabin" which would be 「小【ちい】さなゴンドラにいる四人【よにん】」? In that it can be considered an abbreviation of the latter and can have similar meaning in the right context but に or "in" in the former are also free to interact with other elements in the whole sentence since it's not confined to being a relative clause?

Answer (score 2):

“4 people in a cabin”

This sentence means “小さなゴンドラにいる四人” in Japanese.

“4 people who are in a cabin” it means 小さなゴンドラにいる4人 as well.

「に」this word doesn’t have that meaning like ある、いる

小さなゴンドラに四人
it means also “4 people in a cabin” This type of grammar is called
**体言止め (Taigendome)**
This grammar is to make sentence with noun or pronoun at the end of the sentence.
This technique is used to make sentences more rhythmical and shorter.

Ex normal version:

> A “旅行はどうだったの？”
> How was your trip?
>
> B “小さなゴンドラに4人いたから、狭くて、嫌になっちゃったよ。”
> There were 4 people in a cabin and it was cramped. So I was fed up with it.

体言止め　version :

> A “旅行はどうだったの？”
> How was your trip?
>
> B “**小さなゴンドラに4人**、狭くて、嫌になっちゃったよ。”
> There were 4 people in a cabin and it was cramped. So I was fed up with it.

Ex2 normal version

> ドアをあけ、前を見たら、そこには綺麗な景色がありました。私はすぐに写真を撮りました。
> After I opened the door and looked forward ,there were so beautiful view. So I took a picture immediately.

体言止め　version

> ドアをあけ、前を見たら、**そこには綺麗な景色**。私はすぐに写真を撮りました。
> After I opened the door and looked forward ,there were so beautiful view. So I took a picture immediately.

Comment: So in summary, it's just that いる is being elided?