# 「ずっとお母さんがコーチは嫌だ」

Tags: grammar, syntax, relative-clauses

> ずっとお母さんがコーチは嫌だ
> I don't want my mom to always be my coach.

I am wondering what grammatical role お母さんがコーチ takes. Is it a noun phrase? Why is there nothing between コーチ and は. Also do these work?

> ずっとお母さんがコーチなのは嫌だ
>
> ずっとお母さんがコーチだって嫌だ

I'm also trying to make sense of a sentence of similar construction.

> 高校にはいるまで、浩治はずっとお父さんがコーチのクラブチームで野球をやってきましたから、野球でいやな目にあうなんてことはなかったんです。

Why does it work without having to be お父さんがコーチであるクラブチーム? の marked relative clause?

Comment: I'm confused by your suggested alternative forms.  What do you think コーチ means here?  That might clarify things for you.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi "Coach"

Answer (score 2):

I feel ずっとお母さんがコーチ is a noun phrase that has been nominalized without an explicit nominalizer. [This sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/95259/5010) may be understood the same way. I don't know the rule as to when this is allowed, but I think this "implicit nominalization" happens only with nouns and suru-verbs (usually in informal Japanese).

- ずっとお母さんがコーチがいい。
- あの人が犯人でいいと思う。
- 彼女が優勝は信じられない。
- 僕が発表より彼が発表の方がいいと思います。
- お酒飲んでから運転は絶対にダメ。
  <sub>(お酒飲んでから**の**運転は or お酒飲んでから運転**する**のは is the "standard" form, but の can be omitted for some reason)</sub>
- ひとりで勉強は大変です。
- 渋谷でディナーは久しぶりです。

The following does not work:

- ❌ 1人で学ぶは大変です。: Wrong

---

お父さんがコーチのクラブチーム is an example of something that can be called a の-marked relative clause. A double-subject sentence `AはBがNだ` can become `BがNのA`. For example, この本は表紙が緑色だ → 表紙が緑色の本 (green-covered book), この魔物は頭が鳥だ → 頭が鳥の魔物 (bird-headed monster).

Answer (score 0):

ずっとお母さんがコーチなのは嫌だ ◎

[or ◎(normal)コーチだなんて、◎(written expression)コーチなどというのは、○(informal)コーチっていうのは]

ずっとお母さんがコーチだって嫌だ　X (wrong)

These sentences is possible to be separated into the following sentences.

“ずっとお母さんがコーチ” なのは嫌だ。

“ずっとお母さんがコーチ” entire of this sentence is doing a role of NP (noun phrase) in this sentence.

So these sentence are supposed to be translated into “I don’t want my mother to be coach for a long time.”

(In Japan,coach (コーチ) just means instructor of the club activity.)

父さんがコーチのクラブチーム

This の grammar is called 「格助詞」(case-marking particle)
Strictly there are three usages of 格助詞 but in this case,this の is used express the relationships between nouns and nouns.
And furthermore,this grammar which is used to express the relationships between nouns and nouns is separated into 4 usages.
To express

> 1,Possession

> 2,Belongings

> 3,Disposition

> 4,Superordinate and subordinate words.(上位語と下位語)

お父さんがコーチのクラブチーム
In this sentence,there is の between コーチ and club team. This usage is 4th one. Called 上位語と下位語(Superordinate and subordinate words.)
In this usage,this の is interchangeable with 〜である
So it means, “The club team which my father is coaching.”

Comment: 「ずっとお母さんがコーチだって嫌だ」とは言わないですよね。「ずっとお母さんがコーチなんて嫌だ」か「ずっとお母さんがコーチだなんて嫌だ」ならいいですけど。

Comment: 「ずっとお母さんがコーチだって(そんなのは)嫌だ」この”そんなのは”の省略で会話文体では使われるケースもあると思います。

Comment: あ〜おそらく文法的には間違ってるんでしょうね、けど”ない”と書いちゃうとまずいんで「会話体で存在はするが、文法的には不適」と訂正いたしました。ご指摘感謝です。

Comment: Re "In Japan, coach (コーチ) just means instructor of the club activity." 文芸部コーチ？生徒会コーチ？鉄道研究部コーチ？

Comment: Umm..when I was in junior high school, I heard サッカーコーチ、野球コーチ etc..mainly for the exercising club activity.  So 文芸部 and 鉄道研究部 are not adequate compared with soccer or baseball club.

Comment: But both of them are enough understandable for Japanese people. But 生徒会コーチ,this word doesn’t exists. Because 生徒会 is not club activity.

Comment: I see. Thank you.